# How to use Python Selenium to get the data?

Tags: python, html, web, selenium-webdriver

The link is here : http://www.imei.info/phonedatabase/790-alcatel-9109-mb2/

I can already open this website using `Selenium-Webdriver` in Python. Now I'm trying to get the `battery type` from this website.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim_dddd - can you show us what you've written so far, and describe how that is working or not working? Your question doesn't tell us at what point you are running into difficulties, so it is hard to know how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to get the battery type:

```
 batteryType =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class='cc' and contains(text(), 'Li-Ion')]').text()
```

use the .text() to get the string of an element.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `xpath` as below :-

```
type = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text() = 'Battery:']/following-sibling::div").text
```